# Accessing parts of a memory block (e.g. Char array) atomically in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, strict-aliasing

---

**My use case**

I have a program that manages a large number of data records, each of which with the size of `R` bytes. Each record has a lock whose size is 4 bytes. So in total, each record takes up `S = R + 4` bytes. These records have to be laid in memory next to each other due to application-specific reasons, as illustrated below:

> **.-------------------------------------------------------------------------------.**
>   **|** *lock_1* **|** *data_1* **|** *lock_2* **|** *data_2* **|** ........... **|** *lock_n* **|** *data_n*  **|**
>   **.-------------------------------------------------------------------------------.**

Note that `R` is **not** known at compile time, so I **cannot** statically allocate a record using something like:

```
struct S {
   std::atomic<int> lock;
   char data[R];
} region[N];
```

Therefore, my program allocates a contiguous memory block, in the form of a char array. The array is cache line aligned, and `R` is a multiple of 4, effectively making each lock to be properly aligned:

```
char* region = new char[S*N];   // N is the number of records
```

---

**Question**

How can I use `std::atomic` functions to atomically modify the locks, without actually having to maintain an array of `std::atomic<int>` objects. I can think of two solutions:

1. Given that Linux kernel uses identical bitwise representation for `int` and `std::atomic<int>`, and given that `char*` is an exception to the strict aliasing rule in the sense that it is allowed to point to any type, would it be safe to cast a pointer of type char (which refers to a lock) to `std::atomic`, e.g.:

   ```
   char* x = region + (lockID * S);
   reinterpret_cast<atomic<int>*>(x)->fetch_add(1);
   ```

   where `x` is the memory location of a given lock.
2. If the above solution is not correct (perhaps because it may mess up the strict aliasing optimizations done by the compiler), actually define a lock as an atomic value using placement new:

   ```
   for (int lockID = 0; lockID < N; lockID++) {
        char* memoryOffset = region + (lockID * S);
        std::atomic<int>* lockPtr = new (memoryOffset) std::atomic<int>; 
   }
   ```

   Here, I do not want to keep an array of `lockPtr`s, due to space considerations, so I throw them away, and use the cast from solution 1 to get the pointer to the atomic object of a given lock.

Is any of these solutions correct? If not, what is the right solution?

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast` version is undefined behaviour.  The placement new version looks like it might be ok, not sure about the alignment requirements.

Comment: 1. is incorrect and brokes strict aliasing rules. 2. might be ok, `std::launder` might be useful.

Comment: If your records are guaranteed to be a multiple of 4 bites long, one option is to farm this out to a C function, where the aliasing rules allow the use of a union of atomic int and char[4]. C11 aliasing rules fit this sort of precise memory layout problems better.

Comment: @RichardCritten Isn't a `char*` an exception to the strict aliasing rule in the sense that it is allowed to point to any type? So wouldn't it be safe to cast from `char*` pointer to `std::atomic<int>*` pointer?

Comment: Casting any pointer to a `char *` is defined. Casting from a `char *` to a pointer to another type is only defined if that `char *` was originally cast from a pointer to the same type eg `my_type *` to `char *` back to `my_type *`

Comment: @RichardCritten "_Casting from a char * to a pointer to another type is only defined if that char * was originally cast from a pointer to the same type_" according to?

Comment: @narengi "_Casting from a char * to a pointer to another type is only defined if that char * was originally cast from a pointer to the same type_" as long as alignment is respected, yes

Comment: @Jarod42 "_1. is incorrect and brokes strict aliasing rules_" please cite that rule

Comment: @curiousguy My reading of point (5) in: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast and so long as the _"type aliasing rules"_ are not broken (which I don't think they are).